# PySpark Aggregation on Comma Seperated Column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aggregate

I have a huge DataFrame with two of many columns: `"NAME"`, `"VALUE"`. One of the row value for `"NAME"` column is `"X,Y,V,A"`.

I want to transpose my DataFrame so the `"NAME"` values are columns and the average of the `"VALUE"` are the row values.

I used the pivot function:

```python
df1 = df.groupby('DEVICE', 'DATE').pivot('NAME').avg('VALUE')
```

All NAME values except for `"X,Y,V,A"` work well with the above. I am not sure how to separate the 4 values of `"X,Y,V,A"` and aggregate on individual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to `split` and `explode` the string first:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode 
df = df.withColumn("NAME", explode(split("NAME", ",")))
```

Now you can group and pivot:

```python
df1 = df.groupby('DEVICE', 'DATE').pivot('NAME').avg('VALUE')
```